# Making a path symmetric

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume a list of paths `x={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` and I know due to some physics arguments that also the symmetrical path is relevant in my problem. The question is if there is any fast and optimized way to obtain then, in order to get `x={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{-1,-2,-3},{-4,-5,-6}}`

So far, I have done

```
x = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
Do [
 path = x[[iter]];
 xnew = {};
 Do[
  newpos = path[[pos]]*(-1);
  AppendTo[xnew, newpos],
  {pos, 1, 3}];
 AppendTo[x, xnew],
 {iter, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: why not `Join[x, -x]` where x is {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} ?

Comment: i assume you are new to Mathematica. So welcome ! and yes many things are possible :) Try to avoid programming in a procedural way as much as possible. Many built-in functions in Mathematica together with functional programming paradigms will make your life much easier. The more you will try and experiment the clear things will become. Best of luck !